# Derivation of a lagrangian from the equations of the motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, lagrange-interpolation

We know that if we have a lagrangian, then we can get the equations of the motion using the Euler-Lagrange equations. 
My question is about the converse of this statement: If one knows the equations of motion, like $x = 0$ and $2y'' + 3 y^2 = 0$, then how to derive the lagrangian ( or equivalent lagrangians) ?

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/533400/2451

Comment: I modified my question.