# Relation between lagrangian and equations of the motion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

We know that if we have a lagrangian like                                          $$L(\dot{q}_1, \dot{q}_2, q_1 ,q_2 )=(\dot{q}_1q^2_1 + \dot{q}^2_2 + q_1^2 - q_2^3)$$ 
then we can get the equations of the motion i.e.                                                               $$q_1 =0\\  2\ddot{q}^2_2 + 3{q}^2_2 = 0$$ 
using the Euler-Lagrange equations.

> My question is about the converse of this statement:  If one knows the equations of motion, like the above equation, then how can I calculate the lagrangian L (or equivalent lagrangians)?

Comment: This should answer your question https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/recovering-lagrangian-from-equations-of-motion.400567/

Comment: Thank you,I've seen it before; but unfortunatelly it didn't help me.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3555370/11127

Comment: I've modified it; I haven't get any answer yet!